# Python how to print a space

Tags: python, printing, space

I am doing python reasonably well but I'm not sure on how to print a space in my code.

Usually I just type:

```
print("")
```

Is there a more efficient way I can do this?

Comment: That will print an empty line. What exactly do you mean by space?

Comment: With 'space' you mean a new line, rather than - uh - a *space"?

Comment: I mean print a empty line/space. To make things look nicer.

Comment: It does its job well, but was wondering if there was something else I could do

Comment: Print to a new line: Use the special character \n

Comment: also (not directly related) check out [pprint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module for printing data structures nicely.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question well, you want a "space" between the lines, and as some people already answered, `\n` is the choice.

For example, in the following code I place one `\n` to continue the text in the second line, and later I use `\n\n` to go to a new line twice, so I get a blank line separating the text:

```
>>> print('Hi, I am line number 1!\nI am line number two, nice to meet you!\n\nAnd I am line number 4, why is line number 3 so silent?')
```

Result:

```
Hi, I am line number 1!
I am line number two, nice to meet you!

And I am line number 4, why is line number 3 so silent?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accomplish this task, just use "\n".

```
print("Hello\nHow are you doing?")
```

Result:

> Hello
>   How are you doing?

Comment: The question is about space not the new line.

Answer (score -1):

Just put a space in between the string argument of print.

```
print 'a' + ' ' + 'b'
```

output: `"a b"`

Comment: why not just print 'a b' ? or print '{0} {1}'.format('a', 'b') - the latter being for variables

Comment: True. I just wanted to show how to concatenate a space between variable. 'a' stands for anything. In this exemple it is a string type variable.

Answer (score -3):

If you meant a new line (vertical space) then the following works best.

```
print("\n")
```

The `\n` character can be placed anywhere in a string and will be interpreted as a new line.

Comment: That's actually print two newlines. One is your string, `"\n"`, the other is the newline added by `print` ...